# Silverlight Drag and Drop across Canvas or StackPanel

Tags: silverlight, canvas, drag-and-drop, z-index, silverlight-5.0

My question is about to drag and drop functionality in Silverlight 5

```
<Grid Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="130" Background="Transparent" Width="595" MaxWidth="595" Canvas.ZIndex="4" >
<StackPanel x:Name="MainSP" Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelGroup1" Tag="Group1" MinHeight="129" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasGroup1" Tag="Group1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Button x:Name="ToGroup1" Tag="Group1" Cursor="Hand" Click="ToGroup1_Click" Height="20" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="20" Content="Add Here" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.ZIndex="4"  />
        <!--<this:CustomCard x:Name="myCustomCard" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DiscardCard="myCustomCard_DiscardCard" FinishCard="myCustomCard_FinishCard" MouseLeftDown="myCustomCard_MouseLeftDown" >
        </this:CustomCard>-->
    </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I am having XAML structure like thi, there will will up to 7 group for StackPanel and Canvas also.
Now wehen I will get 13 card from server in different group I will dynamically add them to respective canvas group.

Issue is MainSP is 7 group of StackPanel and Canvas now their Canvas's default ZIndex property will be assigned autometically like CanavsGroup1 has 1, and CanvasGroup2 has 2 ans so on...

When I want to drag card from CanvasGroup3 it is draggable all over screen and CanvasGroup 1 and 2 but when I tries to drag it over CanvasGroup4 or 5 it's not working.
I think it's ZIndex property issue.

I tried somany things to give Zindex property of Card and Canvas to max zindex property but then also it's not working.

Is there any solution that I can move card without using Canvas? or bring that Card to front(top) while dragging?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your statement that it is not working? Do you mean the element stops moving? What happens to it then? Does the drag continue if you move the mouse cursor back over CanvasGroup3? Can you share the code that handles dragging?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned all stackpanel and canvas group are fixed up to 7 group here I just put code for 1 stackpanel and canvas group.

But when I will get collection on cards in different different I will add those cards dynamically from code behind, the object is custom control having card detail. And the object is : this:CustomCard x:Name="myCustomCard"

Now I am registering delegate event for leftmousebutton_down, leftmousebutton_up and mouse_move event and implement code for drag & drop in code-behind before add that control to canvas object.

Comment: Now drag and drop is implemented on card means custom control which contains card detail and it's working fine for it's parent canvas and also other canvas which has lower Z-index, for example I picked card from canvas group 3 start dragging I can easily drag it all-over LayoutRoot canvas and also over canvas group 1 & 2.

The problem is it's not working while dragged that card to canvas group 4, 5, 6, 7. That's my problem that I want to drag card all over screen.

Comment: I tried so many things but unsuccessful, I am failed to identify what is issue? where it's Z-index property or I have put those cards in different canvas group and each canvas group is laying in different stackpanel.